# MySQL multiple arguments query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query for the following...

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM calls 
WHERE id IS NOT NULL
AND account_name LIKE '%$account_search%'
AND name LIKE '%$adv_term_det%' OR description LIKE '%$adv_term_det%'
AND type != 'online'
AND marked_completed_by = ''
ORDER BY $sort_by DESC LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page
```

But the results are not the expected values.  The line I suspect is causing the issue is..

```
AND name LIKE '%$adv_term_det%' OR description LIKE '%$adv_term_det%'
```

Which I suspect should be a subquery but after several attempts to use IN I haven't been able to make it work.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM calls 
WHERE call_ref IN
  (SELECT call_ref FROM calls
   WHERE name LIKE '%$adv_term_det%' OR description LIKE '%$adv_term_det%'
  )
AND id IS NOT NULL
AND account_name LIKE '%$account_search%'
AND type != 'online'
AND marked_completed_by = ''
ORDER BY $sort_by DESC LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page;
```

Basically I want to return all records that meet all the other criteria and have `$adv_term_det` in either `name` or `description` as well.

If I use just `AND name LIKE '%$adv_term_det%'` I get the results I expect for that query and likewise if I use just `AND description LIKE '%$adv_term_det%'` but I need to find records that have '`%$adv_term_det%'` in either `name` or `description`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you are not very experienced with complex boolean logic or you just missed the error.  In either case, I would advise you to use parentheses, particularly when mixing `AND` and `OR`.  I think this is the logic you intend:

```
WHERE (id IS NOT NULL) AND
      (account_name LIKE '%$account_search%') AND
      (name LIKE '%$adv_term_det%' OR description LIKE '%$adv_term_det%') AND
      (type <> 'online') AND
      (marked_completed_by = '')
```

Also note that plugging variables directly into the SQL string is dangerous.  You should be using parameters for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks, works great.  I am indeed a work in progress and learning everyday.  I knew about adding parentheses for queries in other languages but wasn't aware you could use them in SQL too.  Just out of curiosity can you clarify what you mean by parameters rather than variables?

Comment: Hmmm . . . The place to start is with parameterized queries.  This is important when you are doing application development.  If you are just playing around now, then it might be a confusion.  At some point, though, you should learn about SQL Injection, dynamic SQL, and parameterized queries.